# Why is my $PATH different when running bash commands inside a process created from C#?

Tags: c#, linux, bash, .net-core

I have a .NET 5 program on CentOS that starts from a systemd service by using a .service file. It needs to execute another program through the command line, so I wrote these codes:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
    Arguments = "-c \"echo $PATH\"",
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
};

var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

When executing from CentOS's terminal, `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/test_user/.local/bin:/home/test_user/bin`.
But running `echo $PATH` using the above code give me `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Why are the 2 $PATH values different?
Searching about $PATH gave me a few results about `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, but I'm not sure how to interprete these files.

Comment: In the way you started the bash process from within C#, it is a non-interactive, non-login invocation. In your terminal, it is an interactive shell. You did not say how you configured your terminal, so I don't know whether it is a login- or non-login invocation there. All this affects which startup files are executed. However, `PATH` should be in the environment. If you have started your C# program from the terminal, it should inherit the PATH, so the error may be elsewhere. You did not say how you were running your program.

Comment: @user1934428 On CentOS from the Application Launcher I choose Konsole to launch the terminal. The C# program is launched through a systemd service by using a .service file with ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/my-program/MyProgram.dll, User=root. I'm not sure if any of those would be considered "login invocation" or not.

Comment: At least it explains why PATH is not invoked. At least it is a non-interactive invocation, and your `.bashrc` is not processed.  See the bash man-page, section `INVOCATION`, on what happens when a bash process starts.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm not entirely clear about the interactive shell description. So me using Konsole is invoking an interactive shell, but launching from C# like my code is invoking a non-interactive shell? I also try to see the value of $BASH_ENV, but `echo $BASH_ENV` gave me a blank line.

Comment: Most likely, yes. Why should it be interactive? You can (as described in the man-page) print the variable `$-`. If it contains the letter `i`, you are in an interactive shell.  `BASH_ENV` is always empty, unless you set it explicitly somwhere, but I don't see why you should want to do it.  I don't understand what you want to gain from printing it....

Comment: @user1934428 I didn't know that BASH_ENV is always empty. If it is then why did `echo $PATH` from my code return `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231356/discussion-between-formicini-and-user1934428).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the above code invoke a non-interactive shell instead of an interactive shell like when using the system console. [From GNU's Bash Reference Manual, section 1.2:](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html)

> Shells may be used interactively or non-interactively. In interactive
> mode, they accept input typed from the keyboard. When executing
> non-interactively, shells execute commands read from a file.

Interactive and non-interactive shells have different ways of checking for `$PATH` value upon starting, as noted in section 6.2. As an interactive shell Bash may read from `etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` to check for `$PATH` values, but as a non-interactive shell Bash only accept whatever in the environment varible `BASH_ENV` to use as `$PATH` value:

> **Invoked non-interactively**
>
> When Bash is started non-interactively, to
> run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in
> the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the
> expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.